# calling function in class library from view in another project in same solution

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, qunit

i have a function in class library like this

===============

```
  public class QUnitTestController : DesignerController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        InitializeModel();

        var designer = ((Designers)(Convert.ToInt32(DesignerId))).ToString();

        ViewBag.ControllerName = designer;

        return View("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("designdocument")]
    public virtual ActionResult GetDesignDocument()
    {
        return GetJson("~/xmldata/Designer/QUnitDesignDoc.xml", true);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("designconfig")]
    public virtual ActionResult GetDesignConfig()
    {

        return GetJson("~/xmldata/Designer/QUnitDesignConfig.xml", true);
    }

    public ContentResult GetJson(string data, bool isUri)
    {
        var document = new XmlDocument();

        if (isUri)
        {
            document.Load(Server.MapPath(data));
        }
        else
        {
            document.LoadXml(data);
        }

        string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(document.DocumentElement);
        return Content(jsonText, "text/html", Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

and i have some jquery code in  a custom view in another MVC project as follows:-`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //var designerDocument = null;
    //var designerConfig = null;
    //var designerController = null;
    //var zoom = null;


        function Test() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "QUnitTest/designdocument",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,//WHY??
                data: param = "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("something went wrong");
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "QUnitTest/designconfig",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,//WHY??
                data: param = "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("something went wrong");
                }
            });

            designerController = new Design.QUnitTestController();

            zoom = 0;
        }





        module("Load Designer Module", {
            setup: function () {
                //Test();
            }
        });
        test("Load Designer", function () {

            ok(true, "body was clicked!");
            var a = designerController.InitializeDesigner(designerDocument, designerConfig, "#designerContainer");
            equal(a, "expected value");
        });





</script>
```

The issue is that i am not able to call the function  in class library. Please tell me what can i do to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a correct route to map urls like "QUnitTest/someaction" to your controller actions:

Check your Global.asax.cs or RouteConfig class and add the following code to RegisterRoutes method:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "QUnitTest",
    url: "QUnitTest/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "QUnitTest", action = "Index" },
    namespaces: new[] { "NamespaceOfQUnitTestControllerClass" }
);
```

Comment: my Global.asax.cs file is empty and i dnt have the RouteConfig file in my project

Comment: check the MVC project, not the class library.

Comment: MVC project will not work correctly without Global.asax. It is an entry point for the application. Search your MVC project for "MapRoute", may be you have some custom class to register routes instead of standard Application_Start handler.

Comment: i checked the complete project but not fount any Application_Start handler.

Comment: what i want to achieve here is only that... ajax method dat i am using should find the controller action method.. it it seems to be not able to do so for some reason as my controller is in a different library project, and thats why it is returning error... instead of success.

Comment: ajax method generates post request to 'QUnitTest/action' url. MVC application is using routing to map url to specific controller and action. So you need a route to map an url to specific action call. If no routes are defined, than no actions will be executed at all (in both MVC and CL projects). If you have some working actions in MVC project then you should search it for some code that handles route registration.